# copy folder from another computer in the same network without password

Tags: networking, passwords, copy

I Have two computer in the same network. a want copy htdocs folder from computer 'A' to computer 'B', but i don't have computer 'A' password. My os is windows.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the computer's operating system is Unix like, and you have access to the shell you can set up ssh key based authentication. You can read about how you can do that in these links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/how-to-ssh-to-remote-server-using-a-private-key
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Once you have that set up you can user `rsync` or `scp` to copy your folder.

Comment: Oh, my os is windows

Comment: Then you should edit your question to give more details. It is hard to help with so little.